# Is delegate still unsafe unretained?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm reading BNR 3rd Edition, and it says that `delegate` is `unsafe unretained` instead of `weak` by default for backwards compatibility. And I was wondering if this is still true for the newest version of Xcode because not many people have the old iOS version anymore?

Comment: if your target had been `iOS5+` you could have used the `weak` before as well.

Answer (score 4):

Delegate nulling is supported in iOS 5.0 and above. If you are targeting 5.0 or above use `weak`.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate of what? Many classes in the system will still have unsafe unretained delegates for various reasons. Your classes should probably have weak ones.

Comment: It was the CLLocationManagerDelegate

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "should not be used". You don't control the weak-ness of delegates in system frameworks, you can't choose weak or not. If you wanted an example of a class that has an unsafe_unretained delegate, NSTableView's delegate is unsafe unretained.

Comment: OK, so the OP should always use `weak`? Then why bring up `unsafe_unretained` if that is only used internally to Apple code and is just an internal implementation detail? The answer implies that there are cases where `weak` should not be used without further clarification. The whole `unsafe_unretained` portion of the answer just adds FUD to the use of `weak`, IMO.

Comment: To expand on why system classes might not use weak: 1) just not updated yet, 2) needs to support garbage collection on OSX, 3) needs to support delegates that aren't compatible with weak (like NSWindow prior to 10.8, for example). Those reasons don't typically apply to non-framework code, hence me saying that you should probably declare your delegates weak, even if not all of Cocoa's are.